# Unable to start eclipse on linux server

Tags: linux, eclipse

I installed the eclipse in linux server, While starting the eclipse I am getting the below error.

```
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-27 15:32:33.157
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:934)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:918)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:514)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
        at
```

What might be the reason for this? I access that linux server through putty.
Thanks

Comment: Your problem seems to have been already addressed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94497/org-eclipse-swt-swterror-no-more-handles-gtk-init-check-failed-while-runnin)

Comment: It is complaining about the display. Two solutions and they may not be the ones that you want. If you want to run Eclipse on a remote linux box how about either using a VNC client on the windows box and a VNC server on the linux box or installing and running cygwin X server on your windows box and connect with ssh -X from a cygwin xterm window, and then invoke eclipse.

Comment: I am unable to see any answer related to this... please ping m ethe link

Comment: Why would you even want to start Eclipse on a server through SSH? I'm smelling a [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here...

Comment: @Mustafasabir Do i need to install cygwin on my windows? I don't want to install any other softwares on the server, so is this way will work for me?

Comment: The link- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94497/org-eclipse-swt-swterror-no-more-handles-gtk-init-check-failed-while-runnin , Besides that I am not sure about cygwin, I use vnc (if i ever have to connect to an unix endpoint) and can run eclipse firefox etc easily, i work mostly on windows servers and take rdc :)

Comment: I tried with mobax term.. able to access the eclipse but it is dead slow to work on. Is there any other tool?

Answer (score 2):

I've made this mistake in the past plenty.  Chances are your X server (that packaged with cygwin or a software like Xming) is not running.  Ensure it is running first and then try to launch eclipse over SSH.

Answer (score 2):

To run applications on the remote machine and display it on your local machine, login to remote machine using following ssh command .

```
ssh -X username@hostIp
```